# sonar coverage of few of the files in the sonar project shows 0 percent coverage inspite of passing junit

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube-scan

In my SonarQube project, the code coverage of few of the files in the project shows 0 percent coverage in spite of passing JUnit tests.

Is this expected or am I missing any functionality.

Comment: If SonarQube reports a 0% coverage on those files that should mean that the underlying code coverage engine reports a 0% coverage. And so that might relate to the way you're launching/configuring your Java code coverage engine ...